# Behavior of rspec let with FactoryGirl

Tags: rspec, factory-bot

I am trying to use FactoryGirl to create a few items for one of my controller specs:

An excerpt:

```
describe ItemsController do
    let(:item1){Factory(:item)}
    let(:item2){Factory(:item)}

    # This fails. @items is nil because Item.all returned nothing
    describe "GET index" do
        it "should assign all items to @items" do
            get :index
            assigns(:items).should include(item1, item2)
        end
    end

    # This passes and Item.all returns something 
    describe "GET show" do
        it "should assign the item with the given id to @item" do
            get :show, id => item1.id 
            assigns(:item).should == item1
        end
    end
end
```

When I change the lets to this:

```
before(:each) do
    @item1 = Factory(:item)
    @item2 = Factory(:item)
end
```

and I puts @s in front of the variables, everything works. Why isn't the version with lets working? I tried changing the lets to let!s and saw identical behavior.

Answer (score 8):

```
let(:item1) { FactoryGirl.create(:item) }
let(:item2) { FactoryGirl.create(:item) }
```

Actually when you do let(:item1) it will do lazy loading, create the object in memory but not save it in database and when you do

```
@item1 = Factory(:item)
```

it will create the object in database.

Try this:

```
describe ItemsController do
    let!(:item1){ Factory(:item) }
    let!(:item2){ Factory(:item) }

    describe "GET index" do
        it "should assign all items to @items" do
            get :index
            assigns(:items).should include(item1, item2)
        end
    end

    describe "GET show" do
        it "should assign the item with the given id to @item" do
            get :show, id => item1.id 
            assigns(:item).should == item1
        end
    end
end
```

let will never be instantiated if you don't call it, while (:let!) is forcefully evaluated before each method call.

or you can do this:

```
describe ItemsController do
    let(:item1){ Factory(:item) }
    let(:item2){ Factory(:item) }

    describe "GET index" do
        it "should assign all items to @items" do
            item1, item2
            get :index
            assigns(:items).should include(item1, item2)
        end
    end

    describe "GET show" do
        it "should assign the item with the given id to @item" do
            get :show, id => item1.id 
            assigns(:item).should == item1
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. This did not fix the problem. At the end my question it says that I already tried this.